# www.localhost.com/magento and Index of /magento page shows up

Tags: magento

I am trying to install Magento on localhost.

actually, I am a beginner of Magento and stackoverflow.

I have followed guide book and I downloaded Magento sample file.. and unzipped the file at `c:/xampp/htdocs/magento`

also modified the host file..

whenever I am trying to enter the

`www.localhost.com/magento`

index of magento page shows up.like ftp server.

How can I open the Magento file as well guide book..

Comment: Can you clarify what file you want to open?

Answer (score 0):

I do not use xammp so I don't know how it's directory structure looks like, but: it looks like you are installing Magento in a subdirectory, right?

If you do so, you have to edit .htaccess. Change RedirectBase to the name of your subdirectory. So here it should be /magento/ And if the RedirectBase line in .htaccess is commented out delete the # at the beginning of that line.

Answer (score 0):

Once magento zip file is unzipped drag the unzipped file in

c:xampp/htdocs/(magento unzipped folder)  --->>  this is root directory of magento

Now we web browser hit this url

http://localhost/(magento unzipped folder name)

if you are hitting this url first time it asks for configuration and admin url name

to access admin panel

http://localhost/(magento unzipped folder name)/admin url name

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be related with your webserver configuration, and not Magento. If you have Apache, for instance, have a look at your configuration file httpd.conf, and check the line that starts with "DirectoryIndex".
You need to have "index.php" as a valid index file. If you don't, just add it right after DirectoryIndex, restart Apache and it should work fine.

/etc/httpd/conf -> usual location for the httpd.conf file (standard installation, RedHat/CentOS family)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on configuration in the `.htaccess` file, you might  need to specify `index.php` in the url as such: `localhost/magento/index.php` or (*www.localhost.com/magento/index.php* as per your comment) to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your virtual host configuration file for the domain name that you are using. If the directory index is missing in the configuration then the apache server will not be able to determine the entry point for the website and will list all of the files.